# Regex to find Text between different chars

Tags: node.js, regex, replace

Im looking for a fast way to get a word in a huge text which starts with "TEST-"

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit "TEST-12345"
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit 'TEST-12345'
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit " TEST-12345 "
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit "TEST-12345" sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit " TEST-12345 "

I have tried to archive this with different loops, but im getting Unexpected identifier everytime

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit "TEST-12345"
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit 'TEST-12345'
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit " TEST-12345 "
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit "TEST-12345" sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit " TEST-12345 "

```
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit "TEST-12345"\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit \'TEST-12345\'\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit " TEST-12345 "\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit "TEST-12345" sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit " TEST-12345 "'.split("\\")
for (var x in text) {
    console.log(text[x])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.match` method.

```
text.match(/TEST-\d{5}/g)
```

Comment: Hm, big thanks but what if the numbers shorter/longer? Is it also possible to get TEST-ABC ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `.match(/(TEST-(\d+|[A-Z]+))/g)` to match digits(\d) or capital letters ([A-Z]).
If it works then you can accept it as the answer